# Xamarin Forms 2.X - ListView with Grid how to call API for each Row that is inserted into my grid rows

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have the following Xamarin forms grid.

```
 <ListView x:Name="liewViewData" ItemsSource="{Binding InfoList}"  ItemAppearing="OnItemApprearing" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected" RowHeight="{Binding ListViewRowHeight}">

      <ListView.Header>
        <StackLayout Padding="10,5,0,5" BackgroundColor="#cccccc">
          <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*" />
              
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" FontSize="Small" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="Demo" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Small" />
            
          </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
      </ListView.Header>

      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
              <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image Source="danger.png" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"></Image>
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Small" />
                            </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
```

What I need is that on the ItemAppearing event for each grid row added I call an API and update the row data such as the image etc.

Any clue on how to do this?

Comment: XF 3 was released almost **four** years ago, and XF 5 is the current version, yet you are specifically asking about XF 2?

Answer (score 0):

You need to data bind the image, implement `OnPropertyChanged` for that field and assign value to it in the event that you mention. Not sure which part you were missing, but as simple as that.

Comment: The part that im missing is what event to use to call the API for every row created? Is it correct to use the ItemAppearing one?

Comment: @VAAA it should work, you probably want to add some logic to avoid clogging on fast scrolling if the list may be long.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you can share me some code so I can undertand better Thanks

Comment: @VAAA you haven't provided the backend code that you have tried. And it is not clear anymore what you don't understand. From all of this it sounds like you want someone to do your job. Sorry.